# Wordpress Gutenberg InnerBlocks renderAppender not showing with template

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I am developing a small plugin that contains two blocks: one `grid/container`, that renders its contents in 3 equal width columns, and a `grid/item`, that is the child of the grid. But the grid is supposed to also allow `core/image` blocks.

To show what I aim for I made a little sketch:
[image: Sketch of the desired block]

As a default layout, when the grid is inserted first, I want 6 `grid/item`s to be displayed. Via deleting items and adding and moving images, admins should be able to adjust the layout to their liking.

But the problem I am facing right now, is that no button to add more children is displayed when I pass a `template` to the InnerBlocks of the `edit` of the container. Even if I manually pass a `renderAppender` prop. But in the official [documentation](https://wp-gb.com/innerblocks/) both props are used in the example section about renderAppender, so this should work together, right?

This is my code:

**edit.js**

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

import "./gridEdit.scss";

export default function Edit() {
    const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ["grid/item, core/image"];
    const MY_TEMPLATE = [
        ["grid/item"],
        ["grid/item"],
        ["grid/item"],
        ["grid/item"],
        ["grid/item"],
        ["grid/item"],
    ];

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <InnerBlocks
                allowedBlocks={ALLOWED_BLOCKS}
                template={MY_TEMPLATE}
                renderAppender={() => <InnerBlocks.DefaultBlockAppender />} //makes no difference
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

Let me know, if you need more code snippets.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found my typo - It should be

```
const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ["grid/item", "core/image"];
```

not

```
const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ["grid/item, core/image"];
```

If the allowed block type does not exist it only makes sense not to display a button to add more blocks :D